# Increase size of percentage values of MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to use a pie chart (com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart, or MPAndroidChart) to display information in my app. However, the percentage values are way too small to be able to be seen. Is there a method that allows me to increase the size of the percentage value texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPAndroidChart]

I cant add a comment because I have low reputation but have you tried setting the Y/X Axis with `axis.setTextSize(12f);`? provide more info pls.

Comment: if its not the Axis values you want to change, you can also customize the DataSet.

`LineData data = new LineData(set1);`

`data.setValueTypeface(typeface);` (Desired font)

`data.setValueTextSize(9f);` (desired data text size)